# Spring framework jdbcTemplate's queryForObject method

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am new to Spring and reading the book "Spring in Action", I have a question about the following example:

```
public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
  return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
      "select id, firstname, lastname, salary " +
      "from employee where id=?",
      new RowMapper<Employee>() {
        public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs,
                int rowNum) throws SQLException {
          Employee employee = new Employee();
          employee.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
          employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));

          employee.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
          employee.setSalary(rs.getBigDecimal("salary"));
          return employee;
        }
      },
      id);
}
```

What is the type of queryForObject(...)'s second parameter "new RowMapper () ...", what kind of Java syntax is that?

It looks like getting a new instance of a class RowMapper, until the curly brace, it look like declaration of class with just one method mapRow. This syntax just look strange and I never saw it in Java.

So would somebody explain what this is?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is one anonymous class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They
>   enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They
>   are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them
>   if you need to use a local class only once.

Comment: Thanks, and it seems like an Anonymous class should always have a parent class/interface?

Comment: @AlfredZhong the anonymous class always extend another class/interface, so yes it need to have a 'parent' where you can override the methods.